# what does notify and wait mean in java?

Tags: java

I have code that I am learning about `Thread`. I don't understand how it works in my code below. My code is working on traffic light processing. Can you explain in code below?

```
public void run(){
    while(!stop){
        try{
            switch(lc){
                case GREEN:
                    Thread.sleep(1000);break;//pause for ten second;
                case RED: 
                    Thread.sleep(2000);break;
                case YELLOW:
                    Thread.sleep(1000);break;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exc){}
         colorChange(); 
    }

}
synchronized void colorChange(){
    switch(lc){
        case GREEN:
            lc=LightColor.YELLOW;break;
        case YELLOW:
            lc=LightColor.RED;break;
        case RED:
            lc=LightColor.GREEN;break;
    }
    changed=true;
    notify();
}
synchronized void waitChange(){
    while(!changed)
         try {
             wait();
             changed=false;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ControlLight.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        }

}
```

Comment: Your code is not a logical one. Each case statement should have break.

Comment: @sunrise76 Each case does have a break.

Comment: sorry. I got it now.

Comment: But still this code seems to be incomplete. run() method should have some more logic

Comment: You might want to have a look at Thread.sleep too. You really don't give your cars as much time as your comment suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The brief to explain is:

```
 - wait() tells the calling thread to give up the monitor and go to sleep until some other thread enters the same monitor and calls notify( ).
 - notify() wakes up the first thread that called wait() on the same object.
```

The detail about Thread, please refer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

**wait( ):** tells the calling thread to give up the monitor and go to sleep until some other thread enters the same monitor and calls notify( ).

**notify( ):** wakes up the first thread that called wait( ) on the same object.

The `wait-notify` pattern is used in a broad set of cases where one thread needs to tell other threads that some event has occurred. These methods are designed to provide a mechanism to allow a thread to block until a specific condition is met.